# Data not being loaded into array after rest call

Tags: angular

I'm facing difficulties with simple Angular/Java application. During rest call, I'm also creating a tile component. Data is being retrived - I can see logs in the network tab and in backend logs, however Tile component is not being created. Here is the code:

main.grid.ts:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './main.html',
  selector: 'album-grid',
})
export class MainGrid implements OnInit {

  private tileDtos: TileDto [];
  private album: AlbumDto [];

  constructor(public dialog: MdDialog, private albumService: AlbumService, private tileUtils: TileUtils) {
    this.album=[];
    this.tileDtos=[];
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
   this.albumService.getAllAlbums().subscribe(p => this.album = p); // here is the call to rest service
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.album.length); // this returns 0
    this.tileDtos = this.tileUtils.buildTile(this.album);
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.tileDtos.length); // this returns 0
  }

}
```

album.service.ts:

```
@Injectable()
export class AlbumService {
  private baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080';

  constructor(private http: Http) {
  }

  getAllAlbums(): Observable<AlbumDto[]> {
    let getUrl = `${this.baseUrl}/getAllAlbums`;
    return this.http.get(getUrl, {headers: AlbumService.getHeaders()}).map(mapAlbums);
  }

  private static getHeaders() {
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
    return headers;
  }
}

function mapAlbums(response: Response): AlbumDto[] {
  let json = response.json();
  let album: AlbumDto[] = json.map(toAlbum);
  return album;
}

function toAlbum(r: any): AlbumDto {
  let album = <AlbumDto>({
    id: r.id,
    albumName: r.albumName,
    owner: r.owner,
    images: r.images,
  });
  console.log("album: ",album);
  return album;
}
```

in the logs on frontend side I can see:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@  0
Building tile
@@@@@@@@@@@@@  0
album: //here I'm seeing full album json populated as it should be.
```

Edit.

To narrow the issue, to my understanding the issue is with the order of loading in the Main.Grid.ts. as I've noticed in the logs, the rest call is being triggered after the code to create the tile element. I've tried to use hardcoded json object, and it was loaded properly.

Comment: Please create a _minimal_ reproduction. There seems to be too much clutter in your code which is not related to your actual question. By isolating the problem, you're likely to find the solution yourself (and learn a couple of things along the way).

Comment: Ok. I see your point, I just thought that providing background is a good idea, clearly I failed with it = ). Please see my update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attempting to log and use the updated value of `this.album` before it has been updated. Take another look at the code you have above:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.albumService.getAllAlbums().subscribe(p => this.album = p); // here is the call to rest service
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.album.length); // this returns  
    this.tileDtos = this.tileUtils.buildTile(this.album);
    console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.tileDtos.length); // this returns 0
}
```

The code `p => this.albums = p` is going to run *asynchronously* once the network call completes. Immediately after invoking this *asynchronous* operation, you attempt to use `this.album`, which will not have been updated yet. Here's a breakdown:

1. You instruct Angular to make a network call, providing it a function to invoke once the data is returned.
2. Before Angular has a chance to make the request, you attempt to access `this.album`, which has not yet been updated and remains as an empty array.
3. Some time later, Angular returns with the data and invokes your callback function, which updates `this.album` but does *not* update `this.tileDtos`.

To fix this issue, you need run to the relevant code in the correct order. e.g.:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.albumService.getAllAlbums().subscribe(p => {
        this.album = p; // here is the call to rest service
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.album.length); // this returns  
        this.tileDtos = this.tileUtils.buildTile(this.album);
        console.log("@@@@@@@@@@@@@  "+ this.tileDtos.length); // this returns 0
    });
}
```

As you can see, this will ensure that the value of `this.album` is set correctly before attempting to use it to update your component.

Answer (score 0):

Does :

this.albumService.getAllAlbums().subscribe(p => this.album = p);

return a promise?  You'd need to attach it to a .then() and do your work there.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new in Angular world, what do you mean by returning a promise? I've used this code in different "application" and it worked fine ie. returned data and put it in html tab.